# availability of 'well known types' in proto3 protocol-buffers

Tags: protocol-buffers

I see that StringValue is the message wrapper for a string message, which I attempt to use in:

```
service SomeService {
  // health
  rpc HealthCheck(google.protobuf.Empty)
    returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
  // create
  rpc CreateSomething(SomeMessageType)
    returns (StringValue) {}

}
```

However, I get a message from protoc like:

> somefile.proto:30:14: "StringValue" is not defined.

I'm using proto3 syntax.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 14):

OK.

I needed:`import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";`

and, to use the fully qualified `google.protobuf.StringValue`

Comment: This (using qualified name) helped me today.  Thank you!!