# C++ Google Protobuf Generated Code for optional values, such as StringValue, Int32Value

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Google Protocol buffers permit some datatypes which are treated as nullable fields.

For example we have:

- `google.protobuf.StringValue`
- `google.protobuf.Int32Value`
- ... and others

I have found it very difficult to try and figure out exactly what these datatypes are, and how they behave. The easiest method I have found is not to look for documentation at all, but to generate the C++ code and try to search through the header file to find out what method names have been generated.

This isn't a great solution though as the generated C++ code is badly formatted and difficult to read. This solution probably wouldn't work very well for very large protobuf definitions.

The official documentation doesn't give any indication as to what these datatypes are either.

See the following link:

https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/cpp-generated/

---

My best guess as to what a `google.protobuf.StringValue` actually is? I would guess that it is translated into a `oneof` type, with only a single option: `string` or `<nothing>` (null).

I came to this conclusion by comparing what method names are generated. It seems like all the methods expected (according to the documentation) for a `oneof` type is the same as is generated for `google.protobuf.StringValue`.

https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/cpp-generated/#oneof-string-fields

My question then consists of two parts:

- Am I correct about my conclusion as to how the protobuf compiler (protoc) treats the nullable field types? (`StringValue`, `Int32Value`, etc)
- Is there any documentation which explicitly defines what the possible nullable types are and how to use them? I looked extensively and couldn't find anything. It is possible that it is in the official documentation and I missed it. The `C#` documentation does discuss code which includes explicit `Nullable<T>` types, and this also hints that my guess might be correct.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I have got someway to finding an answer to my question, but some things are still unclear to me.</del>

---

The first hint comes from the doc page I linked above.

https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#string-value

In particular:

```
StringValue: Wrapper message for string.

Field name  Type    Description
value       string  The string value.
```

This suggests some kind of Message with a single field called `value` of type `string`. (Not nullable.)

I managed to find a file on my system which contains the definitions of these Wrapper Messages. (The hint for how to do this I obtained from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058284/availability-of-well-known-types-in-proto3-protocol-buffers).)

```
$ find / -type f -name 'wrappers.proto' 2>/dev/null
/usr/include/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
```

This contains things such as:

```
// Wrapper message for `string`
message StringValue {
    // The string value
    string value = 1;
}
```

This helps significantly because it explains that `google.protobuf.StringValue` is just another Message type, with a single string field called `value`. (Hence the API use of `set_value`, which "looks different" to other types.)

However this doesn't explain exactly why this type is nullable.

---

There is a further hint from the documentation, on this page.

https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/cpp-generated/

It lists options for fields which are derived from a `Message` definition. The options are:

- Repeated field
- One of field

<del>There is no "just the Message type by itself".</del>

<del>Where as for something like a normal `string`, we have</del>

- Single string
- Repeated string
- One of string

Edit: I have since discovered that all three options, including `Singular Embedded Field` **do** exist. However, for Singular Embedded Message fields, the generated code is effectively the same as would be generated for an `optional` field. Note this is not the same as `Oneof`.

---

The same Protobuf documentation pages do not list `google.protocol.StringValue` among the types, which makes sense because this is not a fundamental type, and it is defined and obtained from the package `google.protocol`.

---

<del>The connection between the definition of the Message `StringValue` and to its eventual use by the compiler to an optional field, is not yet clear to me.</del>

Switching back to the question as to why a `StringValue` is optional, I believe I have figured out the answer:

The following two documentation pages are relevant:

- https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#specifying-field-rules
- https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/cpp-generated/#embeddedmessage

The first of these pages states that by default fields are `singular`, and *not* `optional`. This isn't quite true in the case of an `EmbeddedMessage`, which when generated to code at least *behaves as if it were optional*.

This is explained in the second link where it is stated that methods such as `has_foo` are generated, and `foo` returns the default instance of the type. That is the same as `optional`.